# how can i make query more faster

Tags: mysql

I have one complex queries and which fetches data from database based on search keywords. I have written two query to fetch data based on keyword by joining two tables. And each table contains more than 5 millions of records. But the problem is, this query takes 5-7 seconds to run so the page take more time to laod. The queries are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( `general_info`.`company_name` ), 
               general_info.* 
FROM   general_info 
       INNER JOIN `financial_info` 
               ON `financial_info`.`reg_code` = `general_info`.`reg_code` 
WHERE  ( `financial_info`.`type_of_activity` LIKE '%siveco%' 
          OR `general_info`.`company_name` LIKE '%siveco%' 
          OR `general_info`.`reg_code` LIKE '%siveco%' )
```

Comment: Any time you try to do `LIKE '%word%'`, you will have poopy performance

Comment: Alternative ideas: [MySQL fulltext search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or NoSQL with MapReduce.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses around distinct don't make a difference.  `distinct` is not a function.  So your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT gi.* 
FROM   general_info gi INNER JOIN
      `financial_info` gi
       ON fi.`reg_code` = gi.`reg_code` 
WHERE fi.`type_of_activity` LIKE '%siveco%' OR
      gi.`company_name` LIKE '%siveco%' OR
      gi.`reg_code` LIKE '%siveco%';
```

For the `join`, you should have indexes on `general_info(reg_code)` and `financial_info(reg_code)`.  You may already have these indexes.

The real problem is probably the `where` clause.  Because you are using wildcards at the beginning of the pattern, you cannot optimize this with a regular index.  You may be able to do what you want using full text search, along with the `matches` clause.   The documentation for such an index is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  This will work particularly well if you are looking for complete words in the various names.

Comment: +1. `DISTINCT` is a keyword that applies to the entire SELECT list; wrapping an expression in parens makes no difference. The DISTINCT will have an effect (on the number of rows returned) if there are multiple rows in `financial_info` that match a given row in general_info (i.e. if `reg_code` is not unique in `financial_info`.